# How do I mainloop the ball?

Tags: python, pong

So, as a personal project, I'm trying to build a PONG game. I have set up the window, all the code, the paddles move fine... It's just the ball. The ball moves once, and then never again. I have no clue whether this is an issue with the definition of the ball's movement or if it's just me not understanding how to use mainloop() correctly, but if I knew how to get the ball to keep moving FOREVER, that would be wonderful. If you want me to explain what I intend for the ball to do, look below the code

```
#Setting up the window

from tkinter import *
from time import *

HEIGHT=800
WIDTH=1280
window=Tk()

window.title('PONG!')
c=Canvas(window,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT,bg='black')
c.pack()

MID_X=WIDTH/2
MID_Y=HEIGHT/2
def pongstick():
    return c.create_polygon(0,0, 10,0, 10,70, 0,70, fill='white')
def ball():
    return c.create_oval(MID_X-10,MID_Y-10, MID_X+10,MID_Y+10, fill='white')

pong1=pongstick()
pong2=pongstick()
ballplay=ball()
MID_Y=MID_Y-35
c.move(pong1, 40, MID_Y)
c.move(pong2, WIDTH-40, MID_Y)

#Scores
player1p=0
player2p=0
ballspeed=10

#Movement of the paddles
stickspeed=10
def move_stick(event):
    if event.keysym == 'w':
        c.move(pong1, 0, -stickspeed)
    elif event.keysym == 's':
        c.move(pong1, 0, stickspeed)
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(pong2, 0, -stickspeed)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        c.move(pong2, 0, stickspeed)

#Ball movement logic
ballspeed=10
ballY=ballspeed
ballX=ballspeed
ballXadd=WIDTH/2
ballYadd=HEIGHT/2

def move_ball(ballX,ballY,ballXadd,ballYadd,player1p,player2p):

    #Movement + edge hit detector
    c.move(ballplay, ballX, ballY)
    ballXadd=ballXadd+ballX
    ballYadd=ballYadd+ballY
    if ballXadd > WIDTH:
        player2p=player2p+1
        c.move(ball,MID_X-10,MID_Y-10)
        ballXadd=0
        ballYadd=0

    elif ballXadd < WIDTH:
        player1p=player1p+1
        c.move(ball,MID_X-10,MID_Y-10)
        ballXadd=0
        ballYadd=0

    elif ballYadd > HEIGHT:
        if ballX == ballspeed:
            ballY = -ballspeed
        elif ballX == -ballspeed:
            ballY = ballspeed

    elif ballYadd < HEIGHT:
        if ballX == ballspeed:
            ballY = ballspeed
        elif ballX == -ballspeed:
            ballY = -ballspeed


#GAME!
c.bind_all('<Key>',move_stick)
while 5<7:
    move_ball(ballX,ballY,ballXadd,ballYadd,player1p,player2p)
    mainloop()
```

So, ballX is moving along the x axis, and ballY... Obvious
ballX/Yadd are the variables that set hit detection against the edge of the window. If ballYadd is more or less than the height, then the trajectory will change. If ballXadd is more or less than the width, the ball is returned to the middle, and a point (player1p or player2p, depending on which side it hit) and the trajectory resets.

Comment: `mainloop()` is something you call _once_. If you want an event to repeat, schedule it by sending a callback to `after()`.

Comment: Can you quickly fix my code? I don't know what you mean... Just the part which is necessary

Comment: If you don't know what I mean, do more research about `mainloop()` and `after()`. This isn't a "fix my code" service.